# Generalization of an inequality $0\lt e^6-{\pi}^4-{\pi}^5\lt 0.00002$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, inequality

> **Question** : Is the following true?
>
> For any $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists a triple $(k,l,m)\ (k,l,m\in\mathbb N)$ such that
> $$0\lt e^k-{\pi}^l-{\pi}^m\lt{10}^{-n}.$$

**Motivation** : A friend of mine taught me the following surprising inequality :

$$0\lt e^6-{\pi}^4-{\pi}^5\lt 0.00002.$$

Hence, we know that the answer for the above question is YES for $n=1,2,3,4$. I have no good idea for $n$ in general. Can anyone help?

Comment: If we have even $| e^k - \pi^l - \pi^m| <1$ with, say, $l > m$, then, $\left| \log \pi - k/l \right| \ll a^{-1} \pi^{m-l}$ and so, if $l$ is a fair bit bigger than $m$, we would have an extraordinarily good approximation to $\log \pi$. Unfortunately, as far as I know, we cannot rule this out, but one suspects that such an approximation is unlikely to exist. This would suggest that $|l-m| \ll \log m$. For such pairs $(l,m)$, a heuristic argument suggests that we cannot force $e^k-\pi^l-\pi^m$ to be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: I mean $l^{-1}$ instead of $a^{-1}$ in the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to solve this and other similar problems is by the help of a computer. I've just searched for solutions to all inequalities of the form $|\pm e^a\pm\pi^b\pm\pi^c|\leqslant10^{-2}$, $a,b,c\leqslant100$ , and came up empty, save for the solution you've already presented. If you are interested in this kind of topics, I would recommend reading [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer) [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence) *Wikipedia* articles, as well as using [this](http://www.mrob.com/pub/ries/) site.

Comment: Thanks for your search and relevant information.